# Finite groups without nontrivial core-free subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group. A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called core-free if
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1} = 1.
\end{equation*}
Equivalently, $H$ is core-free if and only if for any subgroup $N$ of $H$, if $N\lhd G$ then $N = 1$.

Now assume groups below are *finite*.

A Dedekind group $G$ (a group such that all its subgroups are normal) has no nontrivial core-free subgroup as
\begin{equation*}
\bigcap_{g\in G}gHg^{-1} = H\ne 1
\end{equation*}
for any nontrivial subgroup $H$ of the Dedekind group $G$. This list includes all abelian groups and Hamilton groups ($Q_8\times A\times B$ with $A$ abelian of odd order and $B = \mathbb{Z}_2^n$ for some $n$).

**My question:**

I aim to characterize *all* finite groups which has no nontrivial core-free subgroups. An example of such group which is not Dedekind is the dicyclic group of order $12$ (see comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979054/is-there-a-non-abelian-group-without-non-trivial-core-free-subgroup)). Is there any sort of classification of such groups?

---

**Added:** The motivation of this question is to find some conditions of subgroups such that quasi-primitivity implies primitivity:

> **Proposition:** If $G$ has a regular subgroup $H$, then $G$ is quasi-primitive if and only if $G$ is primitive.

Note that if $H$ is transitive and has no non-trivial core-free subgroup, then $H$ is regular. The question comes to characterize what $H$ is up to isomorphism.

---

**Added** (Sep 10, 2019):

This is true:

> $G$ has no nontrivial core-free subgroup then if all of the Sylow subgroups of $G$ are not core-free, and inparticular all of the cyclic subgroups of prime order of $G$ are normal.

For example, $C_3:C_4$ (dicyclic, $3$-Sylow is normal and $2$-Sylows contain the center) and $C_7:C_9$ ($7$-Sylow is normal and $3$-Sylows contains the center) both have no nontrivial core-free subgroups.

Also I think the following might be true:

> $C_{p^d}:C_{q^e}$ has no nontrivial core-free subgroups if $(p-1)\nmid q^e$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes. In this case $p$-Sylow is normal and $q$-Sylow contains the center.

Comment: Two observations: First any minimal normal subgroup must be cyclic (this is reasonably obvious). Second if $G$ has simple socle then the embedding of $G$ into $S_n$ for the least $n$ is defined by the action of $G$ on the right cosets of a core-free subgroup of $G$ of largest order, which means that if $G$ has no non-trivial core-free subgroup then $G$ does not embed into $S_n$ for $n<|G|$. Groups with this property were characterised by Johnson in *Minimal Permutation Representations of Finite Groups* and those with simple socle are cyclic of prime power order or generalised quarternion.

Comment: I think your result on the direct product is incorrect - for example if $G=(C_3\rtimes C_4)\times (C_3\rtimes C_4)$ then the diagonal subgroup of $C_3\times C_3\le G$ is core-free

Comment: @RobertChamberlain My bad, I will delete that. Thank you for pointing out and the two observations.

Comment: $G$ has no nontrivial core-free subgroups if and only if every minimal (prime order) subgroup of $G$ is normal.