# Characterizing Lie groups where every core-free subgroup is trivial

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

A subgroup, $H\subset G$, is called core-free if $H$ contains no non-trivial normal subgroups of $G$. One can define $\text{Core}_G(H)$ to be the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $H$. The core-free subgroups, $H\subset G$, are exactly those with $\text{Core}_G(H)=1$.

I am interested in characterizing all Lie groups, $G$, such that all of its core-free subgroups are trivial. That is, I am looking for all groups $G$ where $\text{Core}_G(H)=1$ implies $H=1$.

Example 1: Every subgroup, $H\subset G$, of an abelian group, $G$, is also a normal subgroup, $H\lhd G$. Normal subgroups have $\text{Core}_G(H)=H$. Thus, when $G$ is abelian we have that $\text{Core}_G(H)=1$ is logically equivalent to $H=1$.

Example 2: The above proof actually holds for all Dedekind groups, $G$.

Example 3: [A non-Dedekind example is discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979054/is-there-a-non-abelian-group-without-non-trivial-core-free-subgroup).

But is there a full characterization of these groups? I am particularly interested in the case where $G$ is a Lie group although a result about finite groups could also be interesting.

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to: all subgroups of prime order are normal. For a $p$-group $G$ this means that $\Omega(G)\le Z(G)$ where $\Omega(G)=\langle x\in G:x^p=1\rangle$. There are 69 such groups of order 64.

Comment: For $p>2$, these groups are called $p$-central.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a positive dimensional compact Lie group and each subgroup $H$ of $G$ with trivial core is trivial, then $G$ must be abelian: otherwise $G$ contains a subgroup $K$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}_2$ or $\mathrm{SO}(3)$. In either case we obtain a subgroup with trivial core which is not trivial: for instance, in $\mathrm{SU}_2$ we consider the matrix
$$g=\left( \begin{matrix} \zeta & 0 \\ 0 & \zeta^{-1} \end{matrix} \right)$$ with $\zeta$ a primitive $3$rd root of one. The subgroup $H=\{1,g,g^2 \}$ generated by $g$ has trivial core in $K$ and hence in $G$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito You're right, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. But what if the Lie group is not compact?

Comment: @DanielGrimmer Of course the same kind of idea leads to yet more non-examples: it e.g. $G$ is a Lie group containing a subgroup isomorphic to the continuous Heisenberg group then it cannot satisfy your condition. I will edit my answer a bit, perhaps, if I can think of a nice way to phrase it.

Comment: @DanielGrimmer By the way, off the top of my head I can't think of any example of a connected non-abelian Lie group that satisfies your property (that a subgroup with trivial core is trivial). Do you know of one? I'm starting to suspect that a connected Lie group has this property if and only if it is abelian.

Comment: No, I don't have any examples in mind. You may be right.